# Прозрачные треугольники в блоке слева и справа

Tags: html, css, html5, css3

[image: Картинка]

Как сделать такие прозрачные треугольники слева и справа?

**Вот такое решение я сделал:**
[**DEMO**](https://jsfiddle.net/0gdpxorm/)

```css
.t-title{
  font-family: 'robotoblack';
  font-size: 25px;
  color: #000;
  height: 42px;
  width: 421px;
  display: inline-block;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 0;
  position: relative;
}

.t-title > svg{
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  z-index: -1;
}
```

```html
<div class="t-title">
    <p>заявка на консультацию</p>    
    <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="420" height="42">   
        <polygon points="0,0 420,0 405,21 420,42 0,42 15,21" style="fill:#f7b707;" />  
    </svg> 
</div>
```

Comment: SVG можно сделать фоном для элемента. Вот хорошая статья на эту тему http://frontender.info/using-svg/

Answer (score 4):

Могу предложить два варианта:

1. SVG фоном.

```html
<svg width="420" height="42">
  <polygon points="0,0 420,0 405,21 420,42 0,42 15,21" style="fill:#f7b707;" />
</svg>
```

2. Если высота будет фиксированной, можно для желтого блока через псевдоэлементы `::before` и `::after` добавить [белые треугольники](http://habrahabr.ru/post/126207/).

Comment: Пример с SVG очень крутой) Но как реализовать в него контент?)

Comment: всё)  нашел способ как наложить текст сверху) А можно вопрос: Где вы сгенерировали этот svg код?

Comment: Я сделал это вручную :-) - не слишком тяжело, а вот для сложных фигур есть инструменты на подобии http://vectormagic.com/ или можно  экспортировать изображение в svg в CorelDraw или Adobe Illustrator

Comment: а какие значения регулируют справа и слева треугольики?)

Comment: В примере с svg нет треугольников. Я использовал элемент poligon, который может принимать множество точек x,y(указываются через пробел), и, как следствие, позволяет от рисовать любой многогранник.

Answer (score 4):

В лоб как-то так:

```css
.arrow-right {
 width: 0; 
 height: 0; 
        float: right;
 border-top: 60px solid transparent;
 border-bottom: 60px solid transparent;
 border-right: 60px solid white;
}
.arrow-left {
        float: left;
 width: 0; 
 height: 0; 
 border-top: 60px solid transparent;
 border-bottom: 60px solid transparent; 
 border-left: 60px solid white;
}
.main-rect{
    background-color: #b0c4de;
    height: 120px;
    text-align: center;
    line-height: 120px;
}
```

```html
<div class="main-rect"><div class="arrow-left"></div>Hello, world!<div class="arrow-right"></div></div>
```

Прозрачность просто эмулируется заменой цвета треугольников на цвет фона и все.

Comment: Способ конечно неплохой) Но что делать если фон не слошной? а с рисунком.

Comment: @Alibek http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23758922/transparent-arrow-triangle вот этот вопрос посмотрите, а то лень дальше расписывать. Там кроме svg, псевдоэлементов и этого наивного подхода есть еще пару хороших методов.

Answer (score 0):

Вариант с `clip-path`:

```css
.btn {
  display: block;
  background: orangered;
  color: #fff;
  padding: 1rem 0;
  text-align: center;
  text-decoration: none;
  
  -webkit-clip-path: polygon(0% 100%, 10% 50%, 0% 0%, 100% 0%, 90% 50%, 100% 100%);
clip-path: polygon(0% 100%, 10% 50%, 0% 0%, 100% 0%, 90% 50%, 100% 100%);
}

.btn:hover {
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<a href="#" class="btn">button</a>
```

Для блока шириной в 100px:

```css
.btn {
  display: block;
  background: orangered;
  color: #fff;
  padding: 1rem 0;
  text-align: center;
  text-decoration: none;
  
  max-width: 100px;
  width: 100%;
  
-webkit-clip-path: polygon(0% 100%, 10px 50%, 0% 0%, 100px 0%, 90px 50%, 100px 100%);
clip-path: polygon(0% 100%, 10px 50%, 0% 0%, 100% 0%, 90px 50%, 100% 100%);
}

.btn:hover {
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<a href="#" class="btn">button</a>
```

Фиксированный размеры 200px*50px:

```css
.btn {
  display: block;
  background: orangered;
  color: #fff;
  padding: 1rem 0;
  text-align: center;
  text-decoration: none;
  width: 200px;
  
-webkit-clip-path: polygon(0px 50px, 10px 25px, 0px 0px, 200px 0px, 190px 25px, 200px 50px);
        clip-path: polygon(0px 50px, 10px 25px, 0px 0px, 200px 0px, 190px 25px, 200px 50px);
}

.btn:hover {
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<a href="#" class="btn">button</a>
```

[canIuse](http://caniuse.com/#search=clip-path)

Comment: Процентные значения полигона к тянущимся блокам, по-моему, не очень смотрятся :-)